# how to optimize Less CSS? how to generate 1 minified version of all less files? I am also using modifyVars

Tags: css, optimization, less

Help!

I am using Less CSS and less.js to compile all less file and now i am already done and i am optimizing the site.

I'm trying to search on web on how to optimize less css. I want to have a  1 minified file version of all my less files without generating it to back to css file since i am using modifyVars.

or is there alternative way? any suggestion or recommendation would be much appreciated.

Cheers,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use less.js in a product environment. LESS is a pre compiler you should use the resulting and optimized CSS files.

> or is there alternative way? any suggestion or recommendation would be much appreciated.

Since CSS will be static you should evaluate your `modifyVars` usages and find an alternative:
For example use javascript / jQuery to change the CSS classes on your elements conditional. See also: [How to change the theme color in less css using javascript/jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16008847/how-to-change-the-theme-color-in-less-css-using-javascript-jquery)