# How to update variables in .less file dynamically using AngularJS

Tags: less

I am very much new to AngularJS. I want to update the .less files variable dynamically. But didn't get how to access this .less file using AngularJS.

My code:

style.less

```
@bg-color: #484848;    
.header{ 
     background: @bg-color;
 }
```

I want to update `@bg-color: #484848;` present in the style.less file to some value input by user. How can I get this using AngularJS.

Comment: Maybe this question helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7823204/dynamically-changing-less-variables

Comment: I don't have idea how can I implement this **less.modifyVars({ ..
  
});** function

Comment: I've never used it either, google is your friend :)

Comment: I found some link here -[http://runnable.com/UnP3Yzjpzm8_AAB2/how-to-modify-variables-for-less-js](http://runnable.com/UnP3Yzjpzm8_AAB2/how-to-modify-variables-for-less-js) But, it is not in AngularJS

Answer (score 1):

You should [run Less in browser](http://lesscss.org/usage/#using-less-in-the-browser) to do this. If you load `less.js` in your HTML, the global `less` object come available, so you can use `less.modifyVars()` <strike>and `less.refreshStyles()`</strike> inside your angularJS code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Example - example-example78-production</title>

<link rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css" href="color.less" />
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.0-beta.1/angular.min.js"></script>

<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/less.js/2.3.1/less.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body ng-app="submitExample">
  <script>
  angular.module('submitExample', [])
    .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
      $scope.list = [];
      $scope.text = 'orange';
      $scope.submit = function() {
        if ($scope.text) {
        less.modifyVars({ color : $scope.text });
        }
      };
    }]);
</script>
<h1>Colored text</h1>
<form ng-submit="submit()" ng-controller="ExampleController">
  Enter text and hit enter:
  <input type="text" ng-model="text" name="text" />
  <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

See: <strike>http://plnkr.co/5b1HTkneFXLMGVvXEG8j</strike> http://plnkr.co/edit/Z9tRY3Lol31PMnPUfxQi