# How to update variables with input values in .less file dynamically using AngularJS

Tags: css, angularjs, angularjs-scope, less

I realize a form of this question has been asked before (see [28208451](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28208451/how-to-update-variables-in-less-file-dynamically-using-angularjs)), however, I need to get the input value and then set it as the new value so that other input fields can access it. Here is a [link to my plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/HOYsG4?p=info).

I can enter a new hue but it is not saved when I attempt to change the saturation or lightness. I am sure it is an easy fix (possibly a directive) but for the life of me I cannot wrap my head around it. I am still fairly new at AngularJS ... any help would be appreciated.

```
**controller:** 
angular.module('colorChanger', [])
    .controller('ColorController', [

      function() {
        var vm = this;

        vm.hue = '194.3';
        vm.saturation = '100';
        vm.lightness = '50';
        vm.newHue = function() {
          if (vm.hue) {
            less.modifyVars({
              hue: vm.hue
            });
          }
        };
        vm.newSaturation = function() {
          if (vm.saturation) {
            less.modifyVars({
              saturation: vm.saturation
            });
          }
        };
        vm.newLightness = function() {
          if (vm.lightness) {
            less.modifyVars({
              lightness: vm.lightness
            });
          }
        };
      }

    ]);

**index:**
<ul>
  <li class="bgc-color-base"></li>
</ul>

<form data-ng-submit="color.newHue()" data-ng-controller="ColorController as color">
  <label for="hue">Hue:</label>
  <input type="text" id="hue" data-ng-model="color.hue" />
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
<form data-ng-submit="color.newSaturation()" data-ng-controller="ColorController as color">
  <label for="saturation">Saturation:</label>
  <input type="text" id="saturation" data-ng-model="color.saturation" />
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
<form data-ng-submit="color.newLightness()" data-ng-controller="ColorController as color">
  <label for="lightness">Lightness:</label>
  <input type="text" id="lightness" data-ng-model="color.lightness" />
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>

**less:**
ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  li {
    height: 100px;
    &.bgc-color-base {
    .background-base;
    }
  }
}    

//== color variables
@hue: 194.3; // enter optional hue variable or custom hue range 0-330
@saturation: 100; // saturation range 0-100
@lightness: 50; // lightness range 0-100 (0 = black, 100 = white)
@alpha: 1;

//== base color function
@color-base: hsla(@hue, (@saturation/100), (@lightness/100), @alpha);

//== base color mixins
.background-base(@hue: @hue, @saturation: @saturation, @lightness: @lightness, @alpha: @alpha) {
 background: @color-base;
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what the use case is here, but bear in mind that, according to the less docs '[We recommend using less in the browser only for development](http://lesscss.org/usage/#using-less-in-the-browser)' - if the goal is to have a dynamically up-datable background you can use an ng-style directive to set an inline style on the element. I've [updated your plunkr](http://embed.plnkr.co/Stm0FZ/preview). Personally I think in-browser modifications should be handled with classes or possibly inline styles, rather than involving less.

Comment: I agree with you and normally I would not attempt it but I wanted to create a live demo in an application I am building to demonstrate the behind the scenes generation of a color scheme using less. Here is a [pen](http://codepen.io/MAustinMMDP/pen/MwaEyB) that shows the less code. I realize this has already been done with codepen but I thought it would be fun to create an application with user interaction that does not require manually changing the hue, saturation and lightness variables.

Comment: Actually, either way would require editing the variables but allowing the user interaction in the window would be more dynamic then having to edit the less code manually. Regardless, I now believe just embedding the pen is a better way to go. I think I just got so caught up in making it work I lost sight of whether or not it should ;). Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have common controller for all three inputs otherwise the scope value change in one controller will not be available for the other controller

**OR**

If you want stay with separate controller then you need to create service that will have value of all variable is stored in it. That will share those values across.

Create a single method for updates less variable that will do the trick for you.

**Markup**

```
<body data-ng-app="colorChanger" data-ng-controller="ColorController as color">
  <ul>
    <li class="bgc-color-base"></li>
  </ul>

  <form data-ng-submit="color.updateColor()" >
    <label for="hue">Hue:</label>
    <input type="text" id="hue" data-ng-model="color.hue" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
  </form>
  <form data-ng-submit="color.updateColor()"">
    <label for="saturation">Saturation:</label>
    <input type="text" id="saturation" data-ng-model="color.saturation" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
  </form>
  <form data-ng-submit="color.updateColor()">
    <label for="lightness">Lightness:</label>
    <input type="text" id="lightness" data-ng-model="color.lightness" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
  </form>

</body>
```

**Code**

```
vm.updateColor = function() {
    less.modifyVars({
        hue: vm.hue || 194.3,
        saturation: vm.saturation || 100,
        lightness: vm.lightness || 50
    });
};
```

And on html instead of calling three method on `ng-submit` call only one method `vm.updateColor` that will do `less.modifyVars` with all three variables.

[**Demo Plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/qC0zBRqxZ4FvzKCguZI7?p=preview)

Comment: You are absolutely awesome! Thanks so much. You don't know how great it is to actually see the color I want ... lol!

Comment: I feel like I finally have closure ;)