# ASP.NET changing a LESS variable

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, less

How can I change the value from a LESS variable (#333) with ASP.NET

```
@color: #333;

.logo {
    color: @color;
}
.div {
    background: @color;
}
```

I'm trying to dynamicaly edit a variable value in a LESS-file using the 'Code Behind' so that when the variable @color get changed using coding, all the elements using that variable will also change.

```
... codebehind > change @color = #666;
```

Comment: You can do it with less.js see this SO thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7823204/dynamically-changing-less-variables

Comment: Thanks. So using the less.modifyVars I can change the LESS variable, but how can I combine this so that the value goes from asp.net > modifyVars > variable?

Answer (score 1):

I think it depend how you do compile your Less code.

When your are using [.less](http://www.dotlesscss.org/) you can not use modifyVars by default. modifyVars requires lazy loading and last declaration wins. .less got the `disable-variable-redefines` option:

> Makes variables behave more like less.js, so the last variable definition is used

In Less you can put a variable definition afterwards which overrule all earlier definitions due to lazy loading and last declaration wins. See also

`modifyVars` does not else than putting the variable definition afterwards.

When you are compiling your code node-less (web essentials does) you should be able to use the `modifyVars` option.

Or alternatively when you normally compile main.less you can try to compile a new file (dynamically edit / generated):

```
@import "main.less"
@color: red;
```