# jQuery, altering css class itself

Tags: jquery, css

Is it possible to alter css class with jQuery? For instance if i have this class defined:

```
.my-class{
  right:10px;     
}
```

and now I want to change it to

```
.my-class{
  right:20px;     
}
```

without having to select all the elements of this class with $(".myClass"). The reason i want to do this is that i am adding a lot of elements at run time in js and it would be nice to swap the class definition ahead of time.

.myClass is defined in css file, otherwise i suppose i could have changed its definition with jsf/jstl had it been on the page.

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/622122/how-can-i-change-the-css-class-rules-using-jquery

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Technically you can edit stylesheets with Javascript using the document.styleSheets object but you might find it a lot more work than it's worth. Read this article to get an idea of what a mess it is: http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/changess.html

Comment: Yeah, it's a shame that it's such a mess. It could be useful.

Answer (score 1):

If I was doing this I would do it with inline styles.

```
<div style="right:20px"><!-- blank --></div>

$('div').css('right','10px');
```

The other option is to have two classes and toggle between them using `toggleClass()`

```
<div class="right10"><!-- blank --></div>

$('div').toggleClass('right20');
```

Comment: I would say the same thing. If the styling is too variable, I'd go inline, if there are a set number of options, I would possibly define and toggle them.

Comment: There are only two variations of the class, which makes it simpler. But i would prefer not to query the dom for these elements. The page i'm rendering is huge.

Comment: Your selectors can be made more specific to speed things up.

Answer (score 1):

Add a second class and set the elements to be the second class when you add them? Alternatively you can swap out style sheets at runtime.

http://www.kelvinluck.com/2006/05/switch-stylesheets-with-jquery/