# What is "CSS on-the-fly"?

Tags: javascript, css

What is CSS on-the-fly?
Does JavaScript allow to modify CSS on-the-fly?

Comment: Where did you see the term "CSS on-the-fly"? This is not a standard term that I've seen used.

Answer (score 2):

**Changing an Elements CSS Attributes**

The easiest way to modify CSS on the fly is probably with Jquery:

```
$('#elementID').css("height", "300px");
```

First parameter is the CSS attribute, second is the new value.

Try and steer away from over using this, as it wont degrade nicely probably for people without Javascript enabled.

**Changing CSS Classes**

Related info: [How can I change the css class rules using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/622122/how-can-i-change-the-css-class-rules-using-jquery)

This afaik is not possible on the fly, see above link.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. It does allow you to modify the CSS on the fly.

Comment: Yes, [it does](http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/REC-DOM-Level-2-Style-20001113/stylesheets.html).

Comment: Oops. I misinterpreted the question. Editing. Btw, thanks for the link.

Comment: I agree I gave wrong answer previously. But now I know it allows. Why still downvote ?

Answer (score 1):

You can also use .style to access css styles in javascript eg

```
document.getElementById("anElement").style.width = "300px";
```

Though I think this might only affect single elements

Comment: Yes, modifying the style attribute on a particular element only affects the style of that element; it does not somehow go backwards and find classes or other selectors that apply to the element and modify the values in one or more of them.