# Getting the <style> prototype, CSSStyleRule/CSSRule mess

Tags: javascript, html

I'm in the middle of creating a Javascript framework for my job, supporting the most modern browsers (FF 4+, Chrome, Opera 11+, IE8+). I'm having some problems trying to extend the `prototype` of the style rules (suppose `rule` is a style rule):

1. In Opera (v. 11.64 so far) there's no `CSSStyleRule` object, even if `String(rule) === "[object CSSStyleRule]"`. It's still true that `rule instanceof CSSRule`, but `CSSRule.prototype` is undefined. The only way I know to get the right prototype is `rule.__proto__`.
2. In other browsers (for example, IE) I wish to define the `parentStyleSheet` property.  `"parentStyleSheet" in CSSStyleRule.prototype` is always false, and I preferably don't want to override the native implementation since the a soft coded one isn't exactly cheap (at least, the first time it's run).

Having a style rule available would be enough to let me go on, but these two points are problems since I'm working on a framework, which is defined *before* the document is loaded, so I can't add `<style>` elements to the DOM.

So, what I'm asking is:

1. Is there a way to create a dummy style rule (and eventually its parent style sheet) without the need to attach it to the DOM?
2. How can access to the style rule prototype in Opera?

I fear the answer to the first question is "no".

Comment: I hope this helps a bit: http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/dynamic-style-css-javascript/

Comment: Just curious: why a new framework?

Comment: @Diodeus It's a nice basic tutorial, but unfortunately it still relies on the availability of the DOM.

Comment: Jon: I don't believe there are currently any frameworks that address stylesheet manipulation properly. Most are aimed at using CSS pseudo-code and compiling it to CSS (such as LESS, SASS) rather than live manipulation. I welcome MaxArt's attempt at building one.

Comment: @JonCram It's a lightweight framework that fits out purposes, and gives us the right instruments, which sometimes aren't natively supported on other common frameworks.

Comment: Another point as to why we need this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6683040/which-javascript-framework-can-search-css-stylesheet-rules-and-edit-their-proper

Answer (score 0):

> before the document is loaded, so I can't add  elements to the DOM

If you can't append to document.head then you can do the ugly `document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" ...`. However AFAIK this is not a problem so long as you are appending to document.head - it is what we do in our framework:

```
<script>
    (function(){
        var s='blueskin';
        var link=document.createElement('link');
        var h=document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
        link.type='text/css';
        link.rel='stylesheet';
        link.href='/skins/'+s+'.css';
        h&&h.appendChild(link);
    })();
</script>
```

To dynamically add a stylesheet for an external css file:

```
var link = document.createElement('link');
link.setAttribute('rel', 'stylesheet');
link.type = 'text/css';
link.href = 'http://example.com/stylesheet.css';
document.head.appendChild(link);
```

If you have CSS as a string, then you can add the `style` element dynamically using (This works for all browsers I use, and I think this this works for Opera, but I haven't tried it recently):

```
var styleElement = document.createElement('style');
styleElement.type = 'text/css';
styleElement.rel = 'stylesheet';
setCss(styleElement, css);
document.head.appendChild(styleElement);

function setCss(styleElement, css) {
    if (styleElement.styleSheet) {   // IE
        styleElement.styleSheet.cssText = css || '';
    } else {
        var firstChild = styleElement.firstChild;
        firstChild && styleElement.removeChild(firstChild);
        var textnode = document.createTextNode(css || '');
        styleElement.appendChild(textnode);
    }
}
```

The [cssFx](http://imsky.github.com/cssFx/) project dynamically fixes the CSS of `<link rel="stylesheet"` elements for opera, if you want to do something more complex.

If you don't want to add to the document.head, then you can also add child stylesheets to an existing stylesheet (equivalent to `@import`), although I don't have a snippet for that.

Finally if the stylesheet needs to go into the body, then you would have to use an onload or jQuery $(myReadyFn); event handlers.

Comment: I've already resolved adding a temporary `<style>` element to `document.documentElement`, then retrieving the last of `document.styleSheets`. It's a similar solution, but I wanted to avoid these kind of tricks. I already had no problem at dynamically adding stylesheets to to document or creating new stylesheets (also, I don't think that `rel` is a standard attribute of `<style>` elements). Thank you for your effort, I might accept your answer if nobody gives a solution for a while.