# Override element.styleSheet.cssText

Tags: javascript

I am looking to override `element.styleSheet.cssText` function

```
element = document.createElement("style");
element.styleSheet.cssText = ...

Object.prototype.styleSheet.cssText = function(){
    console.log('override');
}
```

I get an error that styleSheet is null or undefined. I am using Internet explorer so I expect
`stylesheet` to exist.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: `stylesheet` probably does exist... just not on **every** JavaScript Object.  Why not try `Element.prototype.styleSheet...` instead?

Comment: I get an error "object expected" doing that. I need to override the stylesheet object in an file so when it comes to do element.styleSheet.cssText it will use my new implementation

Comment: Also, you may want to look into this similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10653782/getting-the-style-prototype-cssstylerule-cssrule-mess

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**As far as I know, there is no *real* way to override the native `cssText` getter on a [`CSSStyleDeclaration`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleDeclaration) object.**

Let's have a look why:

```
var s = document.createElement('style'),
    style = s.style;

style instanceof CSSStyleDeclaration; //true
```

So far so good, however when we try to set the `cssText` property:

```
style.cssText = 'something';
style.cssText; //(empty string), the native setter did not allow setting an invalid style
```

As we can see, the `cssText` property implements native getters/setters that are invoked when we try to get/set the `cssText` property.

Ok, fine! Let's just redefine the custom `CSSStyleDeclaration.prototype.cssText` getter/setter. Well that doesn't work because it seems the `cssText` property doesn't come from the prototype and even if it would [there's no way to get custom getters/setters](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=520882) using [`Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertyDescriptor) so we would not be able to invoke the native setter from our custom function.

Let's have a look anyway:

```
Object.defineProperty(CSSStyleDeclaration.prototype, 'cssText', {
    get: function () { return 'overrided'; }
});

document.createElement('style').style.cssText; //(empty string)
```

Is there a solution then? Well there's probably no safe solution to do it yet, but your best bet would be to replace the `style` property with a custom accessor on the newly created element. That accessor would return an object that implements the same interface a `CSSStyleDeclaration` instance would, but all the accessors/functions would have been replaced to delegate the operations to the original style object.

The returned object would basically act as a proxy object for the real style object. That would be the only way since we cannot access native getters/setters functions, otherwise we could have redefined the `cssText` accessor only on the native style object of the element.

In the following example, I demonstrate the idea by only proxying the `cssText` property.

*Note: The reason we create an instance of `CSSStyleDeclaration.prototype` is to make sure that `styleProxy instanceof CSSStyleDeclaration` remains true.*

**THE IMPLEMENTATION IS INCOMPLETE AND NOT SAFE TO USE**

```
document.createElement = (function (doc, nativeCreateEl) {
    return function() {
        var el = nativeCreateEl.apply(doc, arguments),
            nativeStyle = el.style,
            styleProxy = Object.create(CSSStyleDeclaration.prototype);

        Object.defineProperty(el, 'style', {
            get: function () {
                return styleProxy;
            }
        });

        Object.defineProperty(styleProxy, 'cssText', {
            set: function (styles) {
                console.log('setting cssText');

                nativeStyle.cssText = styles;
            },
            get: function () {
                return nativeStyle.cssText;
            }
        });

        return el;
    };
})(document, document.createElement);

var el = document.createElement('div'),
    s = el.style;

s.cssText = 'test'; //logs setting cssText
s.cssText; //(empty string) -> this is expected
s.cssText = 'color: red;'; //logs setting cssText
s.cssText; //color: red;
```