# How to change the style of elements with same class name

Tags: javascript, css

Using javascript, I want to change the style of class `.s` into

```
.s {
  display: block;
}
```

Why this cannot work:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('s').style.display='block';
```

Comment: Why not create a class for the new styles and append this new class to all of the matching classes?

Comment: @JoshSmickus, those lines are used in the response code of a checkbox.  I want to use that checkbox to control if some elements should be shown.

Comment: So, you could write:
`var elems = document.getElementsByClassName('s');
for(var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
    elems[i].className += " new-class";
}` 
Then define new-class with appropriate styles

Comment: @JoshSmickus, What I really want to say is: because of "...", I don't think it is appropriate to "create a class for the new style and ..."

Comment: What? :S I don't get what you mean?

Comment: @JoshSmickus. I mean, I don't think it is appropriate to "create a class for the new style and ..." for my situation.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

[**`document.getElementsByClassName`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByClassName): returns *a set of elements* which have all the given class names.

You may have multiple elements with this class name.  so you need to provide index like

```
document.getElementsByClassName('s')[0].style.display='block';
```

Inorder to apply for style for all elements with same class name:

```
var ele = document.getElementsByClassName('s');
for (var i = 0; i < ele.length; i++ ) {
    ele[i].style.display = "block";
}
```

Comment: Is there a easy way to change all the items at the same time.

Comment: @FANGYishu go for looping.

Comment: It would be nice if we can change the style sheet directly, not the style of just each elements.

Comment: @FANGYishu if you're trying to change the css rules then take a look at [T.J Crowder's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9153841/1671639)

Answer (score 0):

As  `getElementsByClassName` returns an array you need to make a `for` loop over all found elements:

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('s');
for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    elements[i].style.display = "block";
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
var sCls = document.getElementsByClassName('s');
for(var i in sCls) {
    sCls[i].style.display='block';
}
```

this may work!