# Add/Modify CSS in a <style> tag on with jQuery/javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

**What I want to do:**

I want to add rules and modify existing rules inside of a `<style>` tag with javascript/jQuery.

**Why I want to do it:**

I'm basically building a color scheme editor and when the user changes a value in the form, I want to update the CSS to reflect this change.

**What I've Tried:**

Replacing the entire `<style>` tag with CSS generated by a JS function. This works but seems like a lot of processing for a very small change.

Also I can create container `<div>`s that contain specific CSS classes and simply find/replace their HTML. Exmaple below:

```
  <div id="button_background_cont">
    <style type="text/css">.buttons {background-color:#333333;}</style>
  </div>

  <div id="button_color_cont">
    <style type="text/css">.buttons {color:#ffffff;}</style>
  </div>
```

These both work... but are really clunky and I don't particularly like them.

**Example Of What I Need To Do:**

```
<style type="text/css" id="color_scheme">
   .buttons {background:#333333; color:#ffffff;}
</style>
<input name="button_background" id="button_background" value="#333333" />
<input name="button_color" id="button_color" value="#ffffff" />
```

Change The form elements and make it the following

```
<style type="text/css" id="color_scheme">
   .buttons {background:#ff0000; color:#333333;}
</style>
<input name="button_background" id="button_background" value="#ff0000" />
<input name="button_color" id="button_color" value="#333333" />
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You posted "What I want to do" and "Why I want to do it", which is great! However, you should also post a "What I tried" section.

Answer (score 3):

This would be a basic way of doing it, you could perhaps find a better way to generate styles string, but it would look something like this:

```
    function generateStylesContent(){
        var btnBgr = $("#button_background").val();
        var btnColor = $("#button_color").val();
        var stylesPlaceholder = ".buttons{background:[BACKGROUND];color:[COLOR];}";

        var newGeneratedStyles = stylesPlaceholder
                                 .replace("[BACKGROUND]", btnBgr)
                                 .replace("[COLOR]", btnColor)    

        $('#color_scheme').text(newGeneratedStyles);
    };

    $('.buttons').on('click', function(){
        generateStylesContent();    
    })
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/15s0gr08/2/)

Updated

Comment: Yeah this was my first thought. There are around 30+ options though.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think there's a way for you to target a specific class/style property inside <style> tag to change with JS because as far as the browser is concerned, that content is only text. I'd make a separate JS function that would generate the entire style tag text/content, and you could call upon that method whenever something changes in the input field.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it using j-query the following way

```
$("#button_background").css("color",'blue')
```

Comment: This will get super convoluted and will not work. I need to edit the style tag directly.

Answer (score 0):

While you **can** do that there is easier ways to do (check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9153718/change-the-style-of-an-entire-css-class-using-javascript) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9153718/change-the-style-of-an-entire-css-class-using-javascript)), for example:
using the [class selector](https://api.jquery.com/class-selector/) you can filter all objects that have the "old" class `$( ".oldClass" )` and manipulate what classes they have (instead editing the class) :

filter and [add](https://api.jquery.com/addclass/) the new class

`$( ".oldClass" ).addClass(".newClass")`

and [remove](https://api.jquery.com/removeclass/) the old class

`$( ".oldClass" ).removeClass(".oldClass")`

you can also use [.css](http://api.jquery.com/css/) to change a property :

`$( ".oldClass" ).css("background","#ff0000")`

Comment: I can't change classes as we are building DATA attributes based off these classes and other integrated. Those links provided are interesting thanks.

Comment: @DigitalMC technically .css() won't change the class itself, but will add a overriding property to all elements that have the specified class, so it will produce the same result as editing the class.

Comment: True, but it gets deeper as we have "sub-color schemes" that can overwrite the default template theme for certain pieces of content. This makes the Cascading feature of CSS super nice while adding/removing inline styles will get very arduous.

Comment: Thanks so much for your contribution.

Comment: @DigitalMC essentially if you add a class that has a selector level equal to or greater than, this should be a good contribution, since directly modifying the css style tag will get convoluted.