# change style of a class using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, rangeslider

At first i only want to know if this:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("main-content_datafield").style.width= this.value;
```

is valid to use. If it is i would made a mistake. I want to create a rangeslider that controlls the size of some objects. For this i used javascript to get the value of the slider and added the code from before.
So finaly it looks like this:

> http://jsfiddle.net/oqh16n2u/1/

So what did i do wrong here?

thank you!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Change the style of an entire CSS class using javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9153718/change-the-style-of-an-entire-css-class-using-javascript)

Comment: `getElementsByClassName` returns a DOMElement collection (multiple elements, kind of like an Array). To be able to change properties on them, you need to iterate over them, and use `[0]`, `[1]`, etc.

Comment: Also, you need to add +'px' to your  assignment  to make it work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try utilizing `for` loop to iterate `HTMLCollection` returned by `.getElementsByClassName()` , adding `"px"` after `this.value` to set `width` of element

```
var scale_range = document.getElementById('scale_range');
demo = document.getElementById("demo");

scale_range.onchange = function () {
    demo.innerHTML = this.value;

    var elems = document.getElementsByClassName("main-content_datafield");
    for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
        elems[i].style.width = this.value + "px";
    }
}
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/oqh16n2u/5/

Answer (score 0):

As you are already using jQuery, U can get the desired effect using `css()` method in jQuery.

```
scale_range.onchange = function() {
    demo.innerHTML = this.value;
    $('.main-content_datafield').css('width',this.value+'px');
}
```

Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/MasoomS/oqh16n2u/4/

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there. Here are some issues with your code:

1. `document.getElementsByClassName("main-content_datafield")` returns an an [array-like object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) and not a DOM Element object. So, you'll have to iterate on that array.
2. width property takes in the unit as well.

So you are better off with something like:

`document.getElementsByClassName("main-content_datafield")[i].style.width = this.value + 'px';`
in a loop.

Comment: _"document.getElementsByClassName("main-content_datafield") returns an array"_ See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName

Comment: @guest271314 - Thanks for pointing that out. I'll make an edit and add your reference :)