# Add Class using GetElementsByClassName JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css

I am converting a jQuery site to vanilla javascript and am reaching out for advice on the best way to convert a simple line of jQuery to javascript.

The jQuery
`$(".div_class").css({ display: 'none' });`

Any suggestions doing this in pure javascript using only classes would 
be very helpful.

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change the style of an entire CSS class using javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9153718/change-the-style-of-an-entire-css-class-using-javascript)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use `document.getElementsByName` to get the required element,

```
[].slice.bind(document.getElementsByClassName("div_class"))().forEach(function(itm){
  itm.style.display = "none";
});
```

And convert it to an array by binding the array like object as a `this` value of `slice` and call it. Now iterate over the returned array and set its display property.

Also you can shorten it by using `forEach` directly,

```
[].forEach.bind(document.getElementsByClassName("div_class"),function(itm){
  itm.style.display = "none";
})();
```

Comment: You my friend, are a ninja.

Comment: @newneub :) Glad to help! :)

Comment: You can simplify it even further like this, removing the `slice()` step:

[].forEach.call(document.getElementsByClassName('div_class'), function (el) {
  el.style.display = 'none';
});

Comment: The `.bind` isn't even necessary, since the first argument of `.call` sets the context in which `[].forEach` is called.  `.call` further saves the step of having to execute the bound `forEach` function at the end: `.call` both sets the context _and_ executes the function in one step. :)

Comment: @jpec Everyone are writing in that manner. Just for a change I am writing in this way.. :) I read the algorithm, there will not be any performance drawbacks when we use bind. :)

Comment: Suit yourself.  I just wanted to point that out for anybody else who comes across this.

Answer (score 0):

Select all elements with that class name :

```
var allEls = document.getElementsByClassName('div_class');
```

This comes back with an array so you'll have to loop through each element and change each `display` to `none` like so :

```
for(var i=0; i < allEls.length; i++){
   allElls[i].style.display = 'none'
}
```

Comment: Hey sorry it doesn't come back with an array, it comes back with an array-like object, getElementsByClassName returns an HTML Collection of found elements: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName

Answer (score 0):

Try these lines to do so:

```
var div_class = document.getElementsByClassName('div_class');
for (var div in div_class) {
    div.style.display = 'none';
}
```

I think your confusion is because `document.getElementsByClassName('div_class')` returns one `Array`... and because that I've used a `for..in`-*loop* to iterate over each match of the previous array.

Hope it helps.