# Changing actual css font based on select option chosen

Tags: jquery

I am scripting a page, where a user can add text to a image. Ok and three of the elements are that:

1. they can choose a font
2. they can select the color of the font
3. they can type in their own text.

The select option is:

```
<select id="selectafont" name="selectafont" style="width: 200px;" class="required">
 <option value="null">-- Select a Font ... --</option>
 <option value="folksbold">Folks Bold</option>
 <option value="arial">Arial</option>
 <option value="tahoma">Tahoma</option>
 <option value="verdana">Verdana</option>
 <option value="comicsans">Comic Sans</option>
 <option value="ubuntu">Ubuntu</option>
```

The color ( we use jscolor.com ) color picker.
Its element is:

```
<input id="pick_a_color" class="color" value="f12b63">
```

The input element and js I have working, but its a regular input element. That as you type updates the text within another div.

How do I add the value of the color ( from color ) picker and the font to the css of the DIV.

So lets say my input element is :

```
<input name="add_my_text" class="add_my_text" id="add_my_text" type="text" placeholder="Enter your Text...">
```

And the JS to control this and apend it to a div is:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
 //ad title
 $("#add_my_text").keyup(function() 
  {
  var add_my_text=$(this).val();
  $(".add_my_text").html(add_my_text);
  return false;
  });
 });
```

So that a div on page  updates with the content typed in the input element.
The css of which is:

```
.add_my_text {
position:absolute;
left:150px;
top:40px;
font-size:18px;
 }
```

What I want to do is in the above div class ( dynamically change the font color and the font-family.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. Do you want to change the font+color of every div that has the class .add_my_text when the user selects/changes the color/font from the select above?

Comment: There is another SO thread that may be useful to you at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/622122/how-can-i-change-the-css-class-rules-using-jquery (see the entry that has "Proof of Concept" in bold)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this for the font:

```
$("#selectafont").change(function(){
   var font = $(this).val();
   if (font !== "null")
      $(".add_my_text").css("font-family", font);
});
```

And similar for the colour selection (sorry, I'm not familiar with the jscolor.com colour picker).

Comment: This relies heavily on client side fonts ( so I was gonna use fonts, that we have on the server ) so could you assist in helping us point to those fonts eg fonts/verdana.ttf etc as an example, this way we can update the font style, from server based perhaps on css class.. hence I was getting confused. Regarding the color picker.. as you change the color: via firebug input updated like: <input id="pick_a_color" class="color" value="f12b63" autocomplete="off" style="background-image: none; background-color: rgb(206, 65, 241); color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">

Comment: tried using: $("#pick_a_color").change(function(){
   var color = $(this).val();
   if (color !== "null")
      $(".add_my_text").css("background-color", color);
}); not working tho.

Answer (score 2):

Haven't tested the code below, but if I understand what you're looking for, this should work:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  //ad title
  $("#add_my_text").keyup(function() 
  {
    var add_my_text = $(this).val();
    $(".add_my_text").html(add_my_text);
    return false;
  });
  $('#selectafont').change(function()
  {
    var selected = $(this).val();
    if (selected != "null")
    {
      $('.add_my_text').css('font-family', selected);
    }
  });
  $('#pick_a_color').change(function()
  {
      $('.add_my_text').css('color', '#'+$(this).val());
  });
});
```

Comment: +1 for a more complete answer than mine. Note that you can get the current value of the select directly with `$(this).val()` - you don't have to worry about finding which option was selected.

Comment: Thank you sir, wasn't sure about this one, so I didn't want to mislead @422. I've modified the answer accordingly.

Comment: Sincerely appreciate your guys help, thanks @nnnnn and Lior Cohen