# How do you replace CSS/toggle a large amount of elements?

Tags: jquery

**EDIT:** The question morphed into how to optimize a massive CSS change to 700 or more divs. I'm leaving the old question below to describe my original approach.

I have the following jQuery but it is not behaving as I expect. There are around 700 divs with class gr so hiding them takes a noticeable time. I am trying to do:

1. When "Show/hide Pronunciation" is clicked, immediately change that text to "Working"
2. Wait until all 'div.gr' are hidden/shown
3. "Working" goes back to "Show/hide Pronunciation"

   ```
   $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#togglePron').click(function() {
      $('#togglePron').html("Working...");
      $('div.gr').toggle();
      $('#togglePron').html("Show/hide Pronunciation");
     });
   });
   ...
   ... 
   <div class="pronlink" id="togglePron">Show/hide P</div>

   <div class="gr">hai</div><div class="zi">A</div>
   <div class="gr">nao</div><div class="zi">B</div>  
   etc.
   ```

Thanks to Mike Lentini [there's a jsfiddle for this question.](http://jsfiddle.net/SVf5k/4/)

**[This is the full page I'm working on](http://freezoo.alwaysdata.net/readhash8.py)**

The behavior I observe is that "Show/hide P" takes a noticeable time to change, then it changes briefly to "Working", and it goes back to "Show/hide". So is jQuery bunching together both the html() and .toggle(), instead of running html() first?

This seems to be browser specific because in Opera it does what I want. In IE 7 and Chrome 18, the behavior is as I described. Is there a way to make the behavior I want in Chrome happen? Or a better way to do what I am describing?

Comment: Is it possible for you to put all divs with class "g" into some kind of container div?  Doing a toggle on a single parent element seems to perform muchbetter than on the hundreds of individual divs

Comment: I updated my question with the full page, http://freezoo.alwaysdata.net/readhash8.py and I considered how to restructure it but came short. It would be nice to have the "gr" text all in one line. No, I don't know how to put them together.

Comment: Off topic from your question, but you may want to change the `div`s "#toggleFormBar" and "#togglePron" to `a`s instead. Shouldn't affect your code at all, but generally best practice is for clickables to be anchors.

Comment: @DouglasA.Crosby Thanks for the tip. First, I am not too familiar with CSS. I want the whole width of the bar to be clickable and don't see a clean, obvious way to do that with anchors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to dynamically modify your css styles directly (not per element) using javascript.

In your page, all of the text divs in each `<td>` have a `class='gr'` in them WITH an inline `style="display:block;"`. First I'd move the `display:block;` into the style sheet (preferably into the first position).

Using this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/311437/496405) (and [this page](http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/dynamic-style-css-javascript/#stylesheetproperties), also this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/622193/496405)), I'd go through each of the stylesheets until you got the one your interested in (adding a title to the `<css />` will allow you to easily do this). Remove the display block (which is a simple `stylesheet.deleteRule(<index>)` index will be zero because you put it first in .css). Add a new `display:none;`.

This will essentially change the whole css for the page vs changing them individually PER element as you're forced to do with JQuery.

Maybe not the most popular solution but still allows you to keep your current design (not duplicating the information) and uses css for what its suppose to do (tho 'dynamic').

---

**Follow up:**
Nice find with the ["Totally Pwn CSS with Javascript"](http://www.hunlock.com/blogs/Totally_Pwn_CSS_with_Javascript) .  Does exactly what I would do in your situation (wanted to add it here for posterity :) )

On a side note, someone should make a feature request to JQuery to be able to do something like this with ease. :)

---

**Follow Up 2:** *just realized someone else posted solution this before me*

Another way you can do this is to remove the 'gr' class and add another 'grHide' class.
Check out this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SVf5k/13/) to see what I mean.

Do as I said above, move the inline `display:block;` into the css stylesheet under the .gr class. Add a separate class that does everything .gr does but do a `display:none;` instead.

This should allow you to use jquery AND still have it be very quick. The fiddle is quick anyways.

Comment: I like this answer and it is much cleaner than the other ones suggested. I am just having trouble getting the css changes to work in IE. I tried two methods so far, and will keep looking. They work on Chrome and Firefox. This one was easy to follow http://www.alistapart.com/articles/alternate and the same for this 26 vote answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/622193/1238040 does not work in IE.

Comment: Alright, I found this "Totally Pwn CSS with JS" that totally pwnd the other solutions I tried :)

Comment: http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/11579 added feature request :) hopefully it will eventually make it in.

Comment: Well, the jquery folks' reply was that there are plugins that accomplish this. Worth a try, at least.

Comment: I tried to look around to see what plugin's would allow you to do this with jQuery but didn't find any... Not surprised to say the least... Good luck!

Comment: Looks like the jQuery.Rule plugin does the above. Checkout http://flesler.blogspot.com/2007/11/jqueryrule.html

Comment: Thanks for looking, but I'm not convinced to use it. In the demo page http://flesler.webs.com/jQuery.Rule/ the second to last example returns an error. Maybe it's intentional but I doubt it. I'm thinking the free hosting ads broke his examples. Anyway, I have to admit I'm being selfish and milking the bounty period, hoping for an answer that's even more pwnage. Perhaps it'll also encourage people to come read the question and upvote.

Answer (score 6):

**EDIT :**

Rather than using the toggle function to bind an event, why not just swap in a class on all the elements? This should be *much* faster:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#toggleP').click(function(){
    $('.gr').toggleClass('hidden');
  });
});
```

Then in your CSS, add this style:

```
.hidden { display: none !important; }
```

See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5E45Q/4/) for an example.

**ADDITIONAL EDIT :**

As noted by [kingjeffrey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10020675/10079888#comment12935287_10079888), class-swapping the parent element instead of the child elements is even more efficient:

```
JS:
$('#togglePron').click(function(){
  $('table').toggleClass('hide-pron');
});

CSS:
table.hide-pron .gr { display: none !important; }
```

For a (relatively) small number of children, the difference between these approaches is negligible – but as the child count increases, swapping the parent class can be noticeably faster.

---

**ORIGINAL ANSWER :**

Your element isn't going to update until the `click()` function returns. Here's one way (probably not the **best** way) to do it:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#toggleP').click(function() {
    $('#toggleP').html("Working...");
    setTimeout(
      "$('div.g').toggle(10,function(){$('#toggleP').html('Show/Hide P');});",
      10)
  });
});
```

The `toggle()` is now asynchronous due to being "scheduled" for 10ms in the future via `setTimeout()`. This means the `click()` function can return almost immediately, without waiting on the `toggle()` to complete.

As others have noted, the best option is probably to wrap all of your `div`s in a parent (if this is feasible for your actual code) and then toggle that parent `div`.

JSFiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/5E45Q/

Comment: I should've shown the full page, now I updated the question. http://freezoo.alwaysdata.net/readhash8.py I thought about how to join the "gr" divs and came short. The closest would be putting all the "gr"s together in a line but I couldn't think of how to line it up with the Chinese.

Comment: @HeitorChang: See updated answer that should help improve your use case.

Comment: Yes, this is simple and fast, I wouldn't have thought it would run so quickly. Thank you for the update.

Comment: The class swap is a winner! (assuming no transition effect is required)

Comment: For a slightly faster class based solution (and the original on this answer is so good, this improvement may not be worth the change), you could change the class of the parent table rather than the 700 child elements. This will cause the browser's rendering engine to reflow the page just once. See http://jsfiddle.net/5E45Q/5/

Comment: @kingjeffrey: Good call, since as the number of child elements increases the difference between class-swap approaches becomes more pronounced. I'll edit the answer to include this method.

Answer (score 3):

If you can group all your `div.g`'s in a parent element, you will be able to hide that single parent element without modifying the DOM 700 times. See http://jsfiddle.net/SVf5k/6/

But if that is unavoidable, you can add a short delay before you toggle the `div.g`'s. This will give the js engine an opportunity to change the html on `#toggleP`. See http://jsfiddle.net/SVf5k/5/

Comment: You're right, it would be faster and easier if I grouped them. The way I laid out the information, I just don't see a way how. I added a link to the full page above, http://freezoo.alwaysdata.net/readhash8.py

Comment: As a hack, you could toggle between two divs, one div contains the characters and their pronunciation and the other contains just the characters. This would require each character reside in two locations, only one of which will be shown at any given time.

Comment: Wouldn't I still need the 700 divs for each character? I don't get how toggling divs would run faster, I mean, wouldn't I still need to hide one or the other when the Show/Hide is clicked?

Comment: No, hide #group-1, show #group-2: <div id="group-1"><div class="char-group"><span class="char">character 1</span><span class="pronounce">pronunciation 1</span></div><div class="char-group"><span class="char">character 2</span><span class="pronounce">pronunciation 2</span></div></div><div id="group-2"><div class="char-group"><span class="char">character 1</span></div><div class="char-group"><span class="char">character 2</span></div></div>

Comment: #group-1 would contain all 700 characters and their pronunciations. #group-2 would contain just the 700 characters. So you wouldn't be toggling between 1400 groups, just 2.

Comment: Wonderful, I would never have thought of repeating the same info, it just doesn't feel right superficially, it feels like repeating code. Anyway, the speed difference from 10 seconds to almost nothing makes it worthwhile.

Comment: Oh, I didn't notice you calling it a hack. It sure looks like one. Well, 20 more hours till I can deliver the bounty. Will someone top your hack? :)

Answer (score 2):

**Edit**: My original answer was aimed to address your confusion about why you only saw "Working..." for a brief moment and did not see the effects of `toggle()` until after some time. Upon actually looking at the website you're building, I can see that your real concern is simply making this UI update *faster*, in which case I highly recommend [Justin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10079888/105570) (though I'd also be interested in an explanation of why there is such a huge performance difference there).

---

Short answer: I think what you want is **an asynchronous iterator**, which I've seen hand-rolled on other projects but strangely don't think I've seen in an open source library (doesn't mean it doesn't exist--I just haven't seen it).

[Something like this.](https://gist.github.com/2351944)

And you can see [here](http://jsfiddle.net/SVf5k/8/) that it behaves the way (I think) you expect.

Now, for explanation:

> So is jQuery bunching together both the html() and .toggle(), instead of running html() first?

I don't think it's jQuery; I believe it's browser-dependent behavior that you're seeing, with respect to how the browser's rendering engine processes UI updates from the event loop. I know that a lot of UI implementations do not update UI elements instantaneously but only in between every event that is processed.

With browsers my general observation (and I'm not really an authority on this; you'd have to talk with an actual browser contributor) is that *some* UI updates happen immediately, and *some* don't have a visible effect except on every full pass through the event loop. So it would appear to me that whatever jQuery's doing under the hood for `toggle()` falls under the latter umbrella.

Comment: Dan, the reason that `toggleClass()` is so much faster is that it boils down to a few simple comparisons, an array scan and a string manipulation -- about 25LOC including one "complex" nested call: either `addClass()` or `removeClass()`. Using the `toggle()` effects function results in effects and easing calculations, binding/unbinding handlers, event registration, and other goodies -- I stopped counting after about 3 nested function calls (I was at ~200LOC). The effects function isn't necessarily ill-suited for this type of thing, it just doesn't scale to hundreds of elements very well.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the jQuery docs, you see that `toggle()` has a callback -- though you also have to specify a duration if you want a callback. So your code might look something like:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#toggleP').click(function() {
    $('#toggleP').html("Working...");
    $('div.g').toggle(500, function() {
      $('#toggleP').html("Show/hide P");
    });
  });
});
...
... 
<div class="plink" id="toggleP">Show/hide P</div>
```

If half a second is a good duration for you. See more here: http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

EDIT: Quick jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/SVf5k/

Comment: Good idea with the jsfiddle. I really do have a bunch of divs, on average 600-700. So with that many divs, I'm not getting nice results anymore. This update has around 700 divs in its body: http://jsfiddle.net/SVf5k/2/  Maybe jQuery isn't the place for changes, I need to restructure my html.

Comment: Hm, yeah I can see that it gets a bit slow. I'm not sure if there is a faster way to achieve it.

Comment: It's ok for the toggle to be slow, but I'm looking for immediate feedback on the screen that the toggling started and isn't complete yet.

Answer (score 0):

use `$.ajax()` here fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/SVf5k/10/

```
$(function () {
    $('#toggleP').click(function() {
       $(this).html("...Working...");

        $.ajax({
           success: function(){
              $('div.g').toggle(500, function() {
                     $('#toggleP').html("Show/hide P");
              });
          }
      })
  });
});
​
```