# How to access :before element?

Tags: jquery, css, sass, pseudo-element

I have the following SASS code

```
a.unfavorite{
  width: 20px;
  background-position: -71px -28px;
  text-decoration: none !important;
  &:before {
    content: "un-favorite";
    background: #000;
    color: #fff;
  }
 }
```

In JQuery, I want to be able to access the `:before` element so as to modify it.

I tried doing something like this `$('.unfavorite:before')` but yields no results. Am I doing it wrong?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/622122/how-can-i-change-the-css-class-rules-using-jquery

Answer (score 5, accepted):

CSS pseudo-elements are not technically part of the DOM, and thus cannot be accessed using JavaScript.

What you can do instead is add styles for a second class (anywhere after the first one) and add/remove that class using JavaScript/jQuery.

CSS:

```
a.unfavorite2:before {
  content: "un-favorite2";
}
```

jQuery:

```
$(this).toggleClass('unfavorite2');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/nvqKs/