# Is it possible to change CSS Content with js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using [Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/) in my project and i need small wrapper. I get it from twitters source and it looks like:

```css
section#my-content {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    border: 1px solid #DDDDDD;
    border-radius: 4px 4px 4px 4px;
    margin: 15px 0;
    padding: 39px 19px 14px;
    position: relative;
}
section#my-content:after {
    background-color: #F5F5F5;
    border: 1px solid #DDDDDD;
    border-radius: 4px 0 4px 0;
    color: #9DA0A4;
    content: "Example";
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: bold;
    left: -1px;
    padding: 3px 7px;
    position: absolute;
    top: -1px;
}
```

So is it possible with JS (jQuery) or or somehow different change `content` property dynamically ?

Comment: Have you tried using the jquery `.css` method?

Comment: @awbergs yes, no luck

Comment: Have you tried anything at all, as this should be fairly trivial to figure out with a Google search? At least you'll learn that jQuery can't access pseudo elements !

Comment: Have you tried googling how to change inner content of elements with jquery / javascript?

Comment: @adeneo i tried only `css` from `jQuery`

Comment: You ***can not*** access pseudo elements with jQuery.

Comment: You can probably inject additional style in your header.

Comment: @adeneo i didnt said that solution must be only in jQuery

Comment: possible duplicate of [Manipulating CSS :before and :after pseudo-elements using jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5041494/manipulating-css-before-and-after-pseudo-elements-using-jquery)

Comment: Why are you using content? Would it possibly be a better idea to actually make what you're using a real html element? Is that possible?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You cannot modify pseudo-elements with jQuery (unless you want to add `<style>` tags). You can, however, change your CSS to make this easier:

```
content: attr(data-text);
```

The text will be contained within an attribute on the element:

```
<div data-text="This is the default text">Test</div>
```

Now, you can change the attribute with jQuery and the text will change:

```
$('h1').attr('data-text', 'This is some other text');
```

**Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/8qNjv/**

Answer (score 0):

if you meant, can you modify the `css rules` of a given `css class` using javascript/jQuery, then you cannot do so.

however, you can use  jQuery [.css](http://api.jquery.com/css/) to add new CSS rules dynamically.

read [more about it here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/622122/how-can-i-change-the-css-class-rules-using-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a lot:

```
// style editing
.attr()
.css()

// text editing
.html()
.append()
```

But maybe its better to add what you realy want, post also the html next time. And what you want as result.

Answer (score 0):

```
**Angular template: Define myVar variable in ts file**
```

CSS

```
    .input-container{
     position: relative;
     }

   .input-container:after {
     position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
     top: 10px;
    content: attr(data);
   }

   
   <div class='input-container' [attr.data]="myVar">
    <input type='text'>
    <div>
```