# Is it possible to get an existing CSS rule attribute and than edit it using jQuery

Tags: jquery, css

I have a background-image in my carousel, and i'm trying to add a gradient to it using jQuery.

Here is the CCS code of the element i'm trying to edit:

```
element.style {
padding: 5% 5%;
margin: 0px 0%;
background-image: url(myImgUrl);
background-position: left top;
background-size: contain;
min-height: 427px;
}
```

This is how it should like in the end (after adding gradient)

```
background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0,0,0,0) 20%, rgba(0,0,0,1))+ url(myImgUrl)
```

Here is what I tried

```
      jQuery(function(){
          jQuery(".sa_hover_container").each(function){
                    var img = (this).css("background-image");
                    var newBackground = "linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0,0,0,0) 20%, rgba(0,0,0,1)), "+ img ;
                    (this).css(background-image,newBackground);
          });
       });
```

Is it even possible to do? if so, what am I doing wrong ?

Thanks!

Comment: I have url (img) [edited]!, still doesn't work.

Comment: when alerting img , you get only the url . isn't it ?

Comment: can you post a fiddle ?

Comment: One way to do that is to create css classes and add/remove them with classlist. (But not optimal for your case I think)

Comment: You need quotes around "background-image" for one thing.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I change the css class rules using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/622122/how-can-i-change-the-css-class-rules-using-jquery)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try in this way:

```
jQuery(function(){

    jQuery(".sa_hover_container").each(function){

        var imgStyle = this.currentStyle || window.getComputedStyle(this, false),
        var bgImage = imgStyle.backgroundImage.slice(4,-1);
        var newBackground = "linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0,0,0,0) 20%, rgba(0,0,0,1)), " + bgImage;

        jQuery(this).css(background-image,newBackground);

    });

});
```

In this way you can get the url of background even if defined inside a CSS file.

Answer (score 0):

In first fix your JS code

```
jQuery(function(){
    jQuery(".sa_hover_container").each(function() {
        var img = jQuery(this).css("background-image");
        var newBackground = "linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0,0,0,0) 20%, rgba(0,0,0,1)), "+ img;
        jQuery(this).css("background-image",newBackground);
    });
});
```

Comment: I'm a bit of a newbie still, that totally fixed it. 
ty dear sir.

Comment: (this) -> jQuery(this), some wrong brackets, background-image -> "background-image". When you will use some good IDE like PHPStorm it will show you what is wrong.